# Oracle SQL Crosstab with Sum

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, crosstab

I'm fairly new to Oracle SQL and have been tasked with creating a crosstab report using SQL.  I have a single source table with a simple structure similar to this:

[image: TABLE STRUCTURE]

I'm trying to crosstab the results to show the total staff per state as follows:

[image: DESIRED RESULTS]

Ideally I'd like to dynamically cater for offices opening in new states.

I've been looking into PIVOTS but can't seem to get my head around it.  Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In a [PIVOT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) you can start from a source sub-query.
Then you define what field to aggregate for which titles in another field.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT Company, State, Staff
  FROM YourCompanyStaffTable
  WHERE State IN ('Illinois', 'Texas', 'Tennessee', 'Missouri', 'Kansas', 'Indiana')
) src
PIVOT (
  SUM(Staff)
  FOR State IN (
    'Illinois' as Illinois, 
    'Texas' as Texas, 
    'Tennessee' as Tennessee, 
    'Missouri' as Missouri, 
    'Kansas' as Kansas, 
    'Indiana' as Indiana
  )
) pvt
ORDER BY Company
```

In this query, the new column names are generated from the "State" column.
Note that in the source query there's also a limit on those names.
That's just for efficiency reasons. (less data to pull from the table)

And it'll group the results by the source fields that aren't used in the PIVOT declaration.
In this case it automatically groups on the "Company" column.

So it sums the total "Staff" for each "State" per "Company".

Comment: @Fearthegrimp In SO you can thank someone by liking their answer ;) They receive 10 reputation for each like. And -2 for a downvote. But only do it when you feel it fits the description of that button: 'This answer is useful'. Then again, you'll first have to earn 15 reputation to be able to upvote I think. SO grants rights depending on your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
select company, sum(case when state='Illinois' then staff else 0 end) as  Illinois,
 sum(case when state='Texas' then staff else 0 end) as  Texas,
 sum(case when state='Tennessee' then staff else 0 end) as  Tennessee,
 sum(case when state='Missouri' then staff else 0 end) as  Missouri,
 sum(case when state='Kansas' then staff else 0 end) as  kansas,
sum(case when state='Indiana' then staff else 0 end) as  Indiana from t
group by company
```

Comment: As does this.  2 stones to kill one bird :)

Comment: @Fearthegrimp  but you can accept only one stone in SO :)